# kohana 3.2.3.1 route not working when controller is in a sub folder

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

I've just been given a project for a CRM called Kohana, which i've never heard of until now.

Everthing works ok except for controllers that are in a sub folder and when the controller name isn't just a single word.

This controller is in system/expenses.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_System_Expenses extends Controller_System {

   public $header = 'Expenses';

   public function action_index() {
      
      $this->template->content = view::factory('system/expenses/listings');
      $this->template->content->expenses = expenses::get_all();
   }


   public function action_update() {
      $expenses = expenses::find_by_id(form::get_value('id'));
      expenses::update($expenses, form::data());

      $this->redirect(request::current()->referrer());
   }
}
```

When i try to access /system/expenses it gives a 404. If i then move the controller to the base controller folder it still doesn't work unless i rename the class to Controller_Expenses instead of Controller_System_Expenses which then works on the route /expenses

Here is the bootstrap.php file:

```
Route::set('automate', 'hourly')
   ->defaults(array('controller' => 'cron',
               'action' => 'hourly'
         ));

Route::set('daily', 'daily')
   ->defaults(array('controller' => 'cron',
               'action' => 'daily'
         ));

Route::set('auth', '<action>',
      array(
        'action' => '(login|logout)'
      ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'auth',
        'action'     => 'login',
    ));


Route::set('super', 'system/(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
                'directory' => 'system',
        'controller' => 'settings',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));


Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Dashboard',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

It doesn't matter if i add a route in here specifically for the url, if i remove the "super" route, nothing works in the sub folder, even if i rename the controller to Controller_Expenses inside the "system" controller folder the route i had working of just /expenses still doesn't work.

I'm at a loss of how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

case sensitive directory/class name:

```
'directory' => 'System',
'controller' => 'Settings',
```

trailing slash:

```
'system(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))'
```

defaults for optional parameters:

```
'id' => 0,
```